# How do you write the SQL for a PreparedStatement using a WHERE x IN clause?

Tags: sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT last_name,
       first_name,
       middle_initial
FROM   names
WHERE  last_name IN ('smith', 'jones', 'brown')
```

I need to be able to parameterize the list in the IN clause to write it as a JDBC PreparedStatement.  This list could contain any number of names in it.

Is the correct way to do this:

```
SELECT last_name,
       first_name,
       middle_initial
FROM   names
WHERE  last_name IN (?)
```

and then build a list of parameters?  Or is there a better (more correct) way to do that?

Comment: This was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/alternatives-for-java-sql-preparedstatement-in-clause-issue

Comment: consider that the number of parameters that you can send in IN clause is limited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't out of the box. However, with Spring you can do what you want. See [How to generate a dynamic "in (...)" sql list through Spring JdbcTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981683/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-in-sql-list-through-spring-jdbctemplate)

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL doesn't allow the `IN` clause to be parameterized into a single variable -- only dynamic SQL, the SQL query being constructed as a string prior to execution with the comma separated list of values is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to research this topic, as well. I've been guilty of writing similar code and never felt 100% comfortable with it. I suppose I'd like to find something on "variable SQL parameter lists".

In code, using hibernate, and given a String of comma-delimited order Ids, I've used:

```
Session s = getSession();
Criteria crit = s.createCriteria(this.getOrderListingClass());
crit.add(Expression.sql(String.format("{alias}.orderId in (%s)", orderIds)));
crit.add(Expression.eq("status", OrderInfo.Order_STATUS_UNFILLED));
orders = crit.list();
```

Whereas orderId is really part of a "SELECT x FROM y WHERE IN (%s)".

1. I did run the orderIds String through a validator prior to passing it to hibernate - being fearful of injections, etc.
2. Something else that I've been meaning to do is check the limit on SQL parameters and number of characters in the query. I seem to recall hitting a limit somewhere around 2000+ (with MS SQL). That's something to consider if you go with this approach.

I think this is kludgy... to be passing off that many Ids in a Where-clause, but it's a section of code that needs refactoring. Thankfully, the use case has only seen a handful of Ids queried at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also construct your query as a stored procedure that takes the parameterized list as a varchar. For example, in sql server:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[procedure_name]

        @IN_LIST VARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @SQL = '
            SELECT last_name,
                first_name,
                middle_initial
            FROM names
            WHERE  last_name IN (' + @IN_LIST + ')'

        EXECUTE(@SQL)
    END
```

Just make sure your @IN_LIST is formatted as a string that includes the single quotes and commas. For example in java:

```
String inList = "'smith','jones','brown'";
```

Answer (score 0):

If You use MS SQL Server, try reshape your TSQL to use UDF, Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546114/how-to-select-a-subset-of-results-from-a-select-statement/2546226#2546226) my post can help You