# Java + Oracle: How to query database for a set of values

Tags: java, oracle, spring, jdbc, oracle11g

I would like to do the following

```
private List<Number> getIds(List<String> names) {
    String query = "SELECT id FROM months WHERE name IN (?)";
            ...
    }
```

How can I pass my `List<String> names` to the '?' in the query above? I am looking for a dynamic solution as the size of the given list will vary.

I am using Spring 3.0 with Oracle 11.2.0.2.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you write the SQL for a PreparedStatement using a WHERE x IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381791/how-do-you-write-the-sql-for-a-preparedstatement-using-a-where-x-in-clause)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178479/preparedstatement-in-clause-alternatives?lq=1

Comment: Or using Spring JdbcTemplates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981683/how-to-generate-a-dynamic-in-sql-list-through-spring-jdbctemplate?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a database function which returns a collection and call the function from Java using `CallableStatement`?

By doing so you could eliminate the problem of passing multiple values to `IN` condition.

Regards